# AutoMapper failing to map a simple list

Tags: automapper

I have used automapper for mapping lists in the past, for for some reason it won't work in this case.

```
     public class MyType1 {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }


        public class MyType2 {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
        }

     public void DoTheMap() {
                Mapper.CreateMap<MyType2, MyType1>();
                Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

                var theDto1 = new MyType2() { Id = 1, Description = "desc" };
                var theDto2 = new MyType2() { Id = 2, Description = "desc2" };
                List<MyType2> type2List = new List<MyType2> { theDto1, theDto2 };

                List<MyType1> type1List = Mapper.DynamicMap<List<MyType1>>(type2List);
    //FAILURE.  NO EXCEPTION, BUT ZERO VALUES

                List<MyType1> type1List2 =type2List.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<MyType1>).ToList();
   //SUCCESS, WITH LINQ SELECT
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
Mapper.DynamicMap<List<MyType1>>(type2List)
```

To this:

```
Mapper.Map<List<MyType1>, List<MyType2>>(type2List);
```

DynamicMap is only if you don't know the type at compile time - for things like anonymous types.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy.  Not sure why Dynamic Map doesn't work in this situation though.  Surely it just needs to infer the type from the value being passed in, and map it to the stated type? it seems superfluous to have to state the type being mapped from.

Comment: Unless the runtime type is different than the compile-time type. There's a pull request to address this issue, but we're still working out the details on making sure that it doesn't conflict with existing methods:

https://github.com/jbogard/AutoMapper/pull/17