# Automapper DynamicMap failing to map Lists of anonymous types

Tags: c#, automapper, anonymous-types

I have the following snippet of code.

```
var files = query.ToList();
var testFile = Mapper.DynamicMap<EftFileDto>(files.First());
var filesDto = Mapper.DynamicMap<List<EftFileDto>>(files);
```

`testFile` has a properly mapped value, but filesDto is empty.

It appears dynamicMap works on individual items, but not lists?

`files` is a List of anonymous objects.

**EDIT**: It doesn't work if I use Arrays either.  I can get it to work, but ...

```
        var filesDto = query.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<EftFileDto>).ToList();
```

Comment: Maybe check the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5978050/1241400

Comment: @plurby, that doesn't apply at all, as that question relates to two known types, I have a list of an anonymous type, so I need to use `DynamicMap` instead of `Map`

Comment: I've checked and it works when you use query.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<EftFileDto>).ToList(); syntax. Can you provide the code for your query and DTO so we can help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

> In most mapping scenarios, we know the type we’re mapping to at
>   compile time.  In some cases, the source type isn’t known until
>   runtime, especially in scenarios where I’m using dynamic types or in
>   extensibility scenarios.
>
> The DynamicMap call creates a configuration for the type of the source
>   object passed in to the destination type specified.  If the two types
>   have already been mapped, AutoMapper skips this step (as I can call
>   DynamicMap multiple times for this example).

Source: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/

Shorter version: **DynamicMap** is the same as calling **CreateMap** then **Map**.

Some dummy Person class

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Lets say you have a list of Persons.

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
      persons.Add(new Person { 
                Name = String.Format("John {0}", i), 
                Surname = String.Format("Smith {0}", i), 
                Age = i });
}
```

Then you make a select on persons adding a new property.

```
var anonymousTypes = persons.Select(p => new { 
            p.Name, 
            p.Surname, 
            FullName = String.Format("{0}, {1}", p.Surname,p.Name) }).ToList();
```

To get properly mapped the first person

```
var testFile = Mapper.DynamicMap<Person>(anonymousTypes.First());
```

To get properly mapped all persons you would use

```
var testFiles  = anonymousTypes.Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<Person>).ToList();
```

Comment: You just answered with the solution I posted in my Edit.  The issue is I shouldn't need to be using `.Select` to map each item individually, I should be able to map it as a collection with `Mapper.DynamicMap<EftFileDto[]>(files);`  Individual items work, the list doesn't.  So knowing the structure of the Dto should not matter, as a single item maps correctly.

Comment: I know, i've just provided a test to see if it works. If you find it an issue post it or make a pull request on the project page. Why does it bother you to use Select()?

Comment: It seems hackish, and I'm curious why it's not working as it seems it should.

Comment: +1 for the .Select(Mapper.DynamicMap<...>) bit, that worked for me.